# How Do You Count Contiguous Dates in Microsoft Access SQL Query?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, ms-office

I'm working on a query that requires this, but for the this forum question, I will use a hypothetical scenario as I am mostly interested in the approach than a one-time solution.

Let's say everyday a kid does a good job, his/her teacher records the kid's name and the date he/she did a good job on.

```
Table: Kids
*PID    Name
----    ----
 1      Abigail
 2      Jim
 3      Peter

Table: GoodJobHistory
*KidID     *EventDate
 -----      ---------
 1          1/1/2015
 1          1/2/2015
 1          1/3/2015
 1          1/4/2015
 2          1/1/2015
 2          1/2/2015
 3          1/1/2015
 3          1/5/2015
 2          1/5/2015

* refers to a table key
```

I want a query that will produce something like this:

```
Query: query_GoodJobStreak
KidID     EndOfStreak   ConsecutiveDays
-----     -----------   ---------------
1         1/4/2015      4
2         1/2/2015      2
3         1/1/2015      1
3         1/5/2015      1
2         1/5/2015      1
```

Mostly, I'm looking for either examples, links to resources, or maybe even a brief explanation of how I would go about doing this.

I realize that there are a few resources out there, but they either (a) aren't geared towards Access, (b) only count the latest records and ignore the historical ones, or (c) just didn't work.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is a neat trick you can do to find consecutive ranges.  First, number all the rows in your history table, partitioned by the KidID and ordered by the event date.

```
KidID      EventDate  Number
-----      ---------  ------
1          1/1/2015   1
1          1/2/2015   2
1          1/3/2015   3
1          1/4/2015   4

2          1/1/2015   1
2          1/2/2015   2
2          1/5/2015   3

3          1/1/2015   1
3          1/5/2015   2
```

Then find the numerical difference between the row number and the event date.  To find the "difference" between a date and a number, we first have to convert the date to a number.  Access can do this automatically because dates are actually stored as a number behind the scenes (as # of days since 1/1/1900).

```
KidID      EventDate  Number  EventDateNumber  Diff
-----      ---------  ------  ---------------  ----
1          1/1/2015   1       42005            42004  a
1          1/2/2015   2       42006            42004  a
1          1/3/2015   3       42007            42004  a
1          1/4/2015   4       42008            42004  a

2          1/1/2015   1       42005            42004  b
2          1/2/2015   2       42006            42004  b
2          1/5/2015   3       42009            42006  c

3          1/1/2015   1       42005            42004  d
3          1/5/2015   2       42009            42006  e
```

You should see the pattern already.  Any consecutive set of values shares the exact same difference value!  I've labelled the five consecutive ranges with letters next to the Diff. This is a simple trick that can be exploited to separate the data into sets of consecutive ranges and find the result you are after.

First we need a way to add row numbers to the original data.  This can be done with a simple `DCount` function (note this starts counting at `0` but the logic works out the same):

```
SELECT GoodJobHistory.KidID,
       GoodJobHistory.EventDate,
       DCount("KidID", "GoodJobHistory","KidID=" & [KidID] &
                       " And EventDate<#" & [EventDate] & "#") AS RowNumber
FROM GoodJobHistory;
```

Save the query above separately so it can be referenced by a subquery (I've called it `GoodJobHistoryNumbered` in my example)  Then a simple group-by on the difference between date and RowNumber gets the result we are looking for:

```
SELECT GoodJobHistoryNumbered.KidID,
       Max(GoodJobHistoryNumbered.EventDate) AS EndOfStreak,
       Count(GoodJobHistoryNumbered.RowNumber) AS ConsecutiveDays
FROM GoodJobHistoryNumbered
GROUP BY GoodJobHistoryNumbered.KidID, [EventDate]-[RowNumber];
```

Result:

```
KidID   EndOfStreak ConsecutiveDays
1       1/4/2015    4
2       1/2/2015    2
2       1/5/2015    1
3       1/1/2015    1
3       1/5/2015    1
```